# Mean Value Theorem Application

Tags: real-analysis

My professor posted an assignment online with the question posted below. I feel like there's a mistake in it but I won't be able to speak to him for 2 days. I wanted to run this by the people here to see if I'm correct about the mistake. I'm not actually looking for an answer to the question.

**Problem**

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow 0^+} f(z)z$ exists. Prove there is no function $g$ such that $g'(x) = f(x) \;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

If I let $f(x) = x$ then it seems to contradict what the question is stating since $f(z)*z = z^2$, which has a right handed limit at $0$. And the function $g(x) = x^2/2$ would satisfy the derivative criteria.

Comment: Yes, this sure looks false as stated: in fact any continuous function $f$ gives a counterexample.

Comment: I wonder if he meant also to say that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Hmm. Your example seems correct to me. Perhaps there's another condition missing.

Comment: Maybe what is meant is that $\alpha := \lim_{z \to 0}f(z)$ exists, but $\alpha \neq f(0)$. This would indeed ensure that $f$ is not a derivative.